# Cannot load http links in webview xamarin forms

Tags: c#, webview

I am creating a webview that will load my url link for example "http://test.rf.gd/index" but when I tried to load this in webview xamarin it doesn't load it says net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED

I created a new Cookie webview and it doesn't work too

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace OMA.WebCookie
{
    public class CookieWebView : WebView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty UrlProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Url", returnType: typeof(string), declaringType: typeof(CookieWebView), defaultValue: default(string));

        public string Url
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(UrlProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UrlProperty, value); }
        }

        public CookieCollection Cookies
        { get; protected set; }
    }

    public enum CookieNavigationMode
    {
        Back,
        Forward,
        New,
        Refresh,
        Reset
    }
}
```

How can I load http links in xamarin webview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this config setting in the AndroidManifest.xml, precisely in the *application* tag

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

This will allow your Android application to load http links; to allow it on iOS is another story – you can find the solution [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#ios-and-ats).